# Getting Language Code/Locale from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization, locale

I have succesfully retrieved a language that a Facebook User knows using the Graph API

the JSON looks like the following.

```
languages =     (
    {
        id = 105541139480550;
        name = Indonesian;
    },
    {
        id = 106059522759137;
        name = English;
    },
    {
        id = 103088979730830;
        name = "Mandarin Chinese";
    }
);
```

Those are array of Page of that language.

For example:

http://facebook.com/pages/-/106059522759137 
will redirect to the english language page

How do I get the language code from that from example "en" for english?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no endpoint to get the language codes of the languages object's entries. You can query the `locale` of the user object, but not for each language. I guess you'll need a mapping in your own application between the language on Facebook and the language code.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user